# QT FramelessWindowHint Windows 7 dock to side

Tags: qt, windows-7, screen, qwidget, dock

I have made a QWidget with "Qt::FramelessWindowHint | Qt::WindowMinimizeButtonHint | Qt::WindowSystemMenuHint" windowFlags.

I have reimplemented all Mouse events to be able to move/resize my window.

The last thing I want to do is to be able to get the same behavior as a "normal window" concerning Windows 7 Dock system.

When I move my Window near to the left/right/top side of my screen, with the normal windows, it resizes it to halfWindowSize or full screen.

Any idea how to do that?

Answer (score 0):

Well that will be too obvious but still...

You need to listen `move` event and whenever you detect `top-left <= 0` or `top-right >= SCREEN_WIDTH` you will manually re-size your window. Surely you need to get screen size before all those and calculate half of it and so on.

No need to mention that, in half-maximized state you need to listen and check if the window is moved to restore its previous dimensions.

I really believe there is no trivial way to implement this unless you are to use `winapi`. Well in `winapi` case one can object trivialness and I can't deny.

Please let us know if you eventually come up with an easier solution.